# 'thread' was not declared in this scope error for MinGW on windows 11

Tags: c++, mingw

I have installed minGW and compiling c++ code. Things were all good until I started multi-threading.
Here is a simple snippet that i am trying to run:

```
// C++ program to illustrate the race conditions 
#include <iostream> 
#include <thread> 

using namespace std; 

// Shared resource 
int number = 0; 

// function to increment the number 
void increment(){ 
    
    // increment number by 1 for 1000000 times 
    for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++){ 
        number++; 
    } 
} 

int main() 
{  
    thread t1(increment); 
    thread t2(increment); 
    
    t1.join(); 
    t2.join(); 
    
    // Print the number after the execution of both threads 
    cout << "Number after execution of t1 and t2 is " << number; 
    
    return 0; 
}
```

Now this code starts throwing below errors:

```
D:\SublimeText\C_Cpp\cppTest.cpp: In function 'int main()':
D:\SublimeText\C_Cpp\cppTest.cpp:21:2: error: 'thread' was not declared in this scope
  thread t1(increment);
  ^~~~~~
D:\SublimeText\C_Cpp\cppTest.cpp:22:9: error: expected ';' before 't2'
  thread t2(increment);
         ^~
D:\SublimeText\C_Cpp\cppTest.cpp:24:2: error: 't1' was not declared in this scope
  t1.join();
  ^~
D:\SublimeText\C_Cpp\cppTest.cpp:25:2: error: 't2' was not declared in this scope
  t2.join();
  ^~
[Finished in 614ms]
```

If i run same code on online c++14 compiler, it works without error.

I went through many links and found that c++ threading is supported after c++11. Hence checked my compiler version it is c++14.

g++ -v gives following output:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr=/mingw --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
Thread model: win32
gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)**
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but your code would exhibit *undefined behavior* when running. You have multiple simultaneous access to the global `number` variable, which leads to data-races and UB.

Comment: Side note: GCC6.3 does support C++14, but you have to turn it on with the `-std=c++14` command line option.  Some antique mingw implementations did NOT have thread support in spite of implementing a GCC version that should have had threading support. I strongly recommend upgrading. [Use these instructions to get GCC13 or better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30071634/4581301).

Comment: Side note: After installing the updated build tools make sure the old ones are removed from the system path. If you don't it'll probably look like I sold you a bill of goods when the programs compiled with the new tools find the libraries from the old tools and <expletive deleted> up in hard-to-troubleshoot ways.

Comment: Side note, to avoid data races learn how to use std::scoped_lock and std::mutex (or std::atomic)